# How to calculate sum of changes between the selected columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, count, conditional-statements

I have a data frame containing a number of countries ('A'. 'B', and 'C') and the income group of each country per year. I want to calculate how many times each country switches between different income groups ('L', 'M', and 'H') from 2001 to 2022.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                      '2001': ['L', 'L', 'L'],
                      '2002': ['L', 'M', 'H'],
                      '2003': ['L', 'M', 'H'],
                       .
                       .
                       .
                      '2022': ['M', 'L', 'H']}
```

I haven't made any progress and have looked at a combination of `for` loops of index and series. I tried below but couldn't get any result. Any help would be appreciated.

```py
for row in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(2001,2022):
        df ['count'] = df[df[i]=df[i+1]].count()
```

Comment: Don't presume we know the context.
Please provide runnable code and explain what is an income group.

Comment: Try something like ```sum(df[str(i)] != df[str(i+1)] for i in range(2001, 2022))```.